# A question for matrix in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a textbook in which there are some sentences I could not understand. I hope to get some help.

Let $B$ be a matrix having rank $k$ and $B=[b_1 \quad b_2 \quad \ldots \quad b_k] \in \mathbb R^{n \times k}$. Therefore there exists a nonsingular matrix $A$ such that $A=(A_1,A_2) \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ such that
$$AB = \left[ {\begin{matrix} A_1\\ A_2 \end{matrix}} \right] B= \left[ {\begin{matrix} I\\ 0 \end{matrix}} \right].$$

Where is matrix $A$ from? Which algebraic theorem or proposition guarantee its existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, they are saying that you can do elementary row operations on matrix B and if you carry them through until you've reduced B to it's reduced row echelon form, you will have an Identity matrix with some number of rows of zeros below. To see this you really only need to realize that multiplying matrix $B$ on the left by an $(1\times n)$ row vector is the same as doing an elementary row operation on $B$. So, the matrix $A1$ is just a summary of the elementary row operations that you need to do to fully reduce the first $k$ rows of $B$ to rref, and matrix $A2$ are the row operations that you would do to the last $n-k$ rows of $B$ to make those rows all zeros. Think of doing an LU decomposition of $B$...let $E = L^{-1}$. Then, $A1$ is the top $k$ rows of $E$ and $A2$ is the bottom $n-k$ rows of $E$.

Comment: Thank you @Brad S. Do you mean that $A_1 \in \mathbb R^{k \times n}$ and $A_2 \in \mathbb R^{(n-k) \times n}$. What are sizes of $I$ and $0$ matrices?

Comment: I think $I \in \mathbb R^{k \times k}$ and $0 \in \mathbb R^{(n-k) \times k}$. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. Both of the above are correct.